# React Hooks, setState not working with an async .map call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

So, I'm trying to change a state in my component by getting a list of users to call an api.get to get data from these users and add on an new array with the following code:

```js
function MembersList(props) {
    const [membersList, setMembersList] = useState(props.members);
    const [devs, setDevs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let arr = membersList.map((dev) => {
            return dev.login;
        });

        handleDevs(arr);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [membersList]);

    function handleDevs(membersArr) {
        membersArr.map(async (dev) => {
            let { data } = await api.get(`/users/${dev}`);

              /** If i console.log data here i actualy get the data from the user 
                  but i think theres something wrong with that setDevs([...devs, data]) call
              **/

            setDevs([...devs, data]);
        });
    }
```

but the `devs` state always return an empty array, what can I do to get it to have the actual users data on it?

Comment: use `await` with `Promise.all` to get all the devs at once, and only then call `setDevs` on that data. Do not keep old devs around, discard them and replace with new ones, otherwise your component is a memory leak stacking infinite amount of devs duplicates the more you change your props. It's a shame none of the answers addresses this main issue with your implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you were having is because you were setting devs based on the data from the original render every time due to the closure around handleDevs function. I believe this should help take care of the issues you were having by using the callback method of using setDevs.
This also takes care of some issues with the dependency arrays and staleness in the useEffect hook. Typically using `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` should be your last resort.

```
function MembersList(props) {
    // this isn't needed unless you are using it separately
    const [membersList, setMembersList] = useState(props.members);
    const [devs, setDevs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let arr = membersList.map((dev) => dev.login);
        arr.forEach(async (dev) => {
            let { data } = await api.get(`/users/${dev}`);
            setDevs((devs) => [...devs, data]);
        })
    }, [membersList]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how React works behind scenes.

In short, it saves all the "sets" until it finishes the cycle and just after that actually update each state.

I think that why you do not see the current state updated.

For better understanding read this post: [Medium article](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b)

Comment: i read the article and its very clarifying just a little outdated but it helped me to understand react sets

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `setDevs` uses `devs` which is the version of `devs` when `handleDevs` is defined. Therefore `setDevs` will really only incorporate the data from the last time `setDevs` is called.

To fix this you can use the callback version of `setDevs`, like so:

`setDevs(prevDevs => [...prevDevs, data])`

Also since you are not trying to create a new array, using `map` is not semantically the best loop choice. Consider using a regular `for` loop or a `forEach` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

you call `setDevs` in the async execution loop. Here is the updated `handleDevs` function.

```
function handleDevs(membersArr) {
    const arr = membersArr.map(async (dev) => {
        let { data } = await api.get(`/users/${dev}`);
        return data;
          /** If i console.log data here i actualy get the data from the user 
              but i think theres something wrong with that setDevs([...devs, data]) call
          **/
    });
    setDevs([...devs, ...arr]);
}
```